# Checking valid combination of items in list

Tags: c#

I have a list of items that I need to validate. The list can contain any number of items of the type A, B and C, but before the list can be saved, it must confirm to the following rules:

1. If you have A, you need either B or C
2. If you have B, you need A

I have ended up with the following code (saudo code):

```
bool IsListValid()
{
  var a = list.ContainsAny(A);
  var b = list.ContainsAny(B);
  var c = list.ContainsAny(C);

  if (!a && !b)
    return true;

  if (a && (b || c)
    return true;

  return false;
}
```

I don't like this code.
1. The use of Any three times in a row will potentially iterate the list three times
2. The if's doesn't look good to me.

Of cause it would be better with different variable names and by extracting the test into methods with good names, but I think there are better ways of solving this entirely. I'm just not sure how...

Any tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a simple loop, it's both, comprehensible and efficient.

```
bool containsA = false, containsB = false, containsC = false;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    Type itemType = list[i].GetType();
    if (!containsA) containsA = itemType == typeof(A);
    if (!containsB) containsB = itemType == typeof(B);
    if (!containsC) containsC = itemType == typeof(C);
    if (containsA && (containsB || containsC)) return true;
}
return (!containsA && !containsB);
```

Comment: This solution passes my tests. It ensures only one traversal, and that's good. But on the other hand, the if's is still the same...

Comment: @Vegar: the `ifs` are the same because i've understood them as requirement. But the list is iterated only once maximally. And if it contains A and (B or C), it'll return immediately without having to loop the whole list.

Comment: The rules are fixed, but I hoped you could come up with better ifs to check them... I guess this is as good as it gets.

Answer (score 2):

If it's so important that you only go through the list once, you could do this:

```
bool a = false;
bool b = false;
bool c = false;
foreach(var x in list)
{
  if (x is A) a = true;
  if (x is B) b = true;
  if (x is C) c = true;
}
```

But I'd leave it as it is. If profiling later shows that this code is becoming a bottleneck, you can revisit it then.

As for the `if's`, that looks fine to me. As long as A, B and C are properly named (something like `hasNotifyEmail` or `needsResponse`, something that explains why you want them to work with the specified rules) then it should be easy for others to understand.

Comment: My real code contains better names, and each of the ifs is extracted into methods with an intention revealing name. But I hoped for better logic... Its small amount of data, so you are probably right about waiting for proofs before implementing optimizations.

Answer (score -1):

```
var hasA = list.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(A));
var hasB = list.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(B));
var hasC = list.Any(x => x.GetType() == typeof(C));

//If you have A, you need either B or C
// A AND (B xor C)
if (hasA && (hasB ^= hasC))
   return true;

//If you have B, you need A
if (hasB && hasA)
   return true;

   return false;
```

Comment: Additional note: Although the .Any() extension method is called three times, i think it will break after the first hit. If this is the case, you could probably end much earlier as if you iterate through the whole list like in Adam V's example. Btw: If you have A, you need either B or C means to me: A and (B xor C) and not A and (B or C)

Comment: This solution fails one of my tests. The list is valid if it contains C alone. It could have been mentioned as a third rule, but in my mind, every thing is valid, except when a given rule states otherwise.